# Fatal error в коде PHP

Tags: php

При определенных условиях выскакивает вот такая ошибка -

```
**Fatal error: Call to a member function getError() on a non-object in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 2455**
```

В этой строке находиться такой кусок PHP кода:

```
$info_chief = $hero_pic.",".$form->getError("error").$xp;
```

### Как можно исправить эту ошибку? Поделитесь, пожалуйста, советом, так как из-за нее у меня огромная головная боль! (((

```
class Form {

    private $errorarray = array();
    public $valuearray = array();
    private $errorcount;

    public function Form() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['errorarray']) && isset($_SESSION['valuearray'])) {
            $this->errorarray = $_SESSION['errorarray'];
            $this->valuearray = $_SESSION['valuearray'];
            $this->errorcount = count($this->errorarray);

            unset($_SESSION['errorarray']);
            unset($_SESSION['valuearray']);
        }
        else {
            $this->errorcount = 0;
        }
    }

    public function addError($field,$error) {
        $this->errorarray[$field] = $error;
        $this->errorcount = count($this->errorarray);
    }

    public function getError($field) {
        if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errorarray)) {
            return $this->errorarray[$field];
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function getValue($field) {
        if(array_key_exists($field,$this->valuearray)) {
            return $this->valuearray[$field];
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function getDiff($field,$cookie) {
        if(array_key_exists($field,$this->valuearray) && $this->valuearray[$field] != $cookie) {
            return $this->valuearray[$field];
        }
        else {
            return $cookie;
        }
    }

    public function getRadio($field,$value) {
        if(array_key_exists($field,$this->valuearray) && $this->valuearray[$field] == $value) {
            return "checked";
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function returnErrors() {
        return $this->errorcount;
    }

    public function getErrors() {
        return $this->errorarray;
    }
};
?>
```

Comment: ПЫХПЫХ такой ПЫХПЫХ:)

Comment: @MDJHD, причем тут пых, когда на лицо ошибка в логике кода?

Comment: Ну не будем тут развивать холивары по поводу недостатков пхп, которых у него намного больше, чем преимуществ:)

Comment: @MDJHD, я и не собирался устраивать холивар. Просто не люблю голословных нападок. :)

Comment: Лучше вместо этого класса вставьте нам кусок кода, строк так 20-30, в котором находиться строчка с ошибкой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну так ответ очевиден, $form не является объектом при этих ваших определенных условиях! Чтобы указать конкретно, где ошибка, надо еще предоставить нам код, где этот $form создается.
Можно попробовать так исправить, если это не сильно влияет на логику программы:

```
if(isset($form) && is_object($form))
    $info_chief = $hero_pic.",".$form->getError("error").$xp;
else
    $info_chief = $hero_pic."Неизвестная ошибка или что-то более подходящее для вашего кода".$xp;
```

Comment: Сейчас буду искать...

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Не то вы добавили.
Ищите вот такой код:  

    $form = new Form;

Стоят там какие-нибудь условия?

Comment: Такого кода вообще нет...

Comment: есть только:

global $form;

Comment: @eprivalov1 ctrl + f -> искать $form по всему проекту, но вообще это одна из прекрасных западней PHP

Comment: Скорее всего эта $form еще не была инициализирована, где именно должна пройти инициализация в этой вашей игре (помню по предыд. вопросам) тяжело сказать, попробуйте какой-нибудь программкой для поиска слов в файлах найти где она создается ( по значению *new Form*).

Comment: Ну или в лоб, как я дополнил в ответе

Comment: Ну, еще вариант, так как код не ваш, и если вы вносили в него изменения, после которых он перестал работать, надо попробовать откатить эти изменения

Comment: Самый оптимальный вариант - импортировать проект в IDE.  
Это значительно упростит отладку.  
Из бесплатных - NetBeans. [**Умеет находить точку определения функции или переменной**][1].  

  [1]: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/editorguide_ru.html#goToDeclaration  
Для удобства написания кода придумали много инструментов. Так пользуйтесь ими!  
@MDJHD, добавьте в свою проверку еще и is_object(). Оттуда же ноги растут...